# How to assign an Array of Objects to a control within a FormGroup

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I'm adding a list of objects to an array (demolist) in the below method:

```
updateList(list: any) {
    this.demolist = Array.apply(this, list);
    console.log(this.demolist);
}
```

When a user clicks on the below File Upload control, & adds a document, the above method is envoked.

```
<upload formControlName="fileUpload" #fileUpload (listChange)="updateList($event)" data-kind="primary" [imagePreview]="true" restrictFiles=".pdf,.doc,.docx">
</upload>
```

When the user clicks on the Submit button on my form, this code is then executed:

**HTML:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(emailForm.value)">
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
onSubmit(formContent): void {
    this.postData(formContent);
}
```

But at the moment, the fileUpload control in the form when submitted, does not contain any files.

Can someone please tell me how to add the files in ***this.demolist*** to the ***fileUpload*** control in my emailForm using the *updateList()* method?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't natively support file uploads surprisingly.  You have to do a bit of work to make it happen. What worked for me was that I used jQuery to select the input that the file is uploaded to and then from there I used the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface to get the file and then do what I needed from there. Since I used the standard input to do it, your solution would be a little different than what I have, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
const files = $(`#fileUpload`).prop('files');
if (get(files, '[0].name')) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData;
    formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
    input.value = formData;
}
```